# Ng - repeat to iterate a complex array like this

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array like this

$scope.disArray = [0, -5, -10, -15, [-11, -12,-13, -14], [-12, -13, -14]];

now if the element in the array is direct value then it should input type text,
if it is an array then it should be select with the array of values.

### **Expecting Output like this**

```
<tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>-5</td>
    <td>-10</td>
    <td>-15</td>
    <td>
      <select>
         <option>-11</option>
         <option>-12</option>
         <option>-13</option>
         <option>-14</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
         <option>-11</option>
         <option>-12</option>
         <option>-13</option>
         <option>-14</option>
      </select>
    </td>
```

plz help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried anything before asking for the code to solve your problem?

Comment: Use `ng-if` and a scope method that utilises [`angular.isArray`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isArray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```js
var app=angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
   $scope.isArray = angular.isArray;
   $scope.disArray = [0, -5, -10, -15, [-11, -12,-13, -14], [-12, -13, -14]];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td ng-repeat="value in disArray">
             <span ng-if="!isArray(value)">{{value}}</span>
             <select ng-if="isArray(value)" ng-options="val for val in value" ng-model="selected"></select>
    
           </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$parse/syntax?p0=value&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=8&p3=typeof%20value%20!%3D%3D%20'object'&p4=value%20!%3D%3D%20'object'

Comment: Perfect Thank you Anik Islam Abhi

Answer (score 0):

you can do  it in this way.

HTML :

```
<tr>
    <td ng-repeat="oneEle in disArray">
        <span  ng-if="!isArrayElement(oneEle)" ng-bind="oneEle"> </span>

        <select   ng-if="isArrayElement(oneEle)"  ng-model="oneVal"  ng-options="oneElement for oneElement in oneEle ">
        </select>    
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS :

```
$scope.disArray = [0, -5, -10, -15, [-11, -12,-13, -14], [-12, -13, -14]];

    $scope.isArrayElement = function(arrElement){
        return angular.isArray(arrElement);
    }
```